# How can I dynamically create a class based off ActiveRecord at runtime? (Ruby)

Tags: activerecord, metaprogramming, ruby-1.9.2

I'm experimenting with meta programming and want to dynamically create a class that inherits from ActiveRecord.

For example, I can do this:

```
Object.const_set("Orders", Class.new { def blah() 42 end })
```

So now I can:

```
o = Orders.new
o.blah   #<== 42
```

But when I try to:

```
Object.const_set("Orders", Class.new < ActiveRecord::Base { def blah() 42 end })
```

Gives me a syntax error and

```
Object.const_set("Orders", Class.new { def blah() 42 end } < ActiveRecord::Base)
```

Doesn't complain until I try to instantiate an `Orders` class

Any tips?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to do this:

```
SomeClass = Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base) do
  .... #some behaviour
end
```

Comment: HA!!!  I actually literally JUST FOUND OUT how to do this and I came here to answer my own question.  LOL  But since you beat me to it, I gave you the +1 and answer credit.  Here is how I did it:  `Object.const_set("Computers", Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base) {})`  Now, `Computers.all` works like a champ.  Thanks!